# How to make Radio button check in cakephp with dynacmic value

Tags: php, cakephp

```
echo $this->Form->input('Client.brainstorm_question.', 
    array('selected' =>$selected,
        'hiddenField'=>false,
        'div' => false,
        'legend'=>false,
        'type'=>'radio',
        'options'=>$bquetion,
        'label'=>false,
        'class'=>'ml0 form-control'));
```

Comment: You need to learn to be more precise and detailed in your questions. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->input('Client.brainstorm_question.', 
     array('value' =>'B',
        'hiddenField'=>false,
        'div' => false,
        'legend'=>false,
        'type'=>'radio',
        'options'=>array('1'=>'A','2'=>'B'),
        'label'=>false,
        'class'=>'ml0 form-control'));
```